# Uso CAPICOM para assinatura no Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, assinatura-digital

Estou utilizando a `capicom.dll` no delphi para realizar a assinatura em arquivos (planejado em .pdf). Já consegui ler os certificados `My` da área `CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE`.

Porém tenho o seguinte problema no `IF` abaixo:

```
if (cert.HasPrivateKey) And (cert.ValidFromDate <= Now) And (cert.ValidToDate >= Now) then
  begin
  { assinar um documento }
  end;i
```

O problema está no `(cert.HasPrivateKey)`. Ele está sempre retornando `Inaccessible value` no `watch`. Alguém sabe me dar uma mão?
Obs: Se estiver desatualizado esse método, me avisem por favor!

Comment: `Inaccessible value` não é um problema, ele esta lhe informando que não pode mostrar um valor, claro, `HasPrivateKey` é um método e não uma propriedade.

Comment: no exemplo que estou seguindo, ele faz aquele teste... seria errado fazer o teste então?

Comment: Não, não é, estou dizendo que ele não é um problema.

Comment: Amigo, você tem conhecimento sobre essa rotina? Na minha fonte ele utiliza essa validação (o if inteiro). obs: tenho 2 certificados em minha máquina